# Failed thread should not pick same data from CSV file, already read by thread in queue

Tags: jmeter

***Precondition:***
**Threads**: 5, **Loop Count**:5

CSV config file contains: IP  address and Mac address 
[image]

***Scenario***:
When Thread execution starts, 5 threads reads values of IP address and Mac address from CSV file.
T3 fails in execution and looping of threads starts, it  picks Ist ip and ist mac address from CSV and that is already picked by ist threads and is in queue(Completing end to end flow).

How to handle like all the threads in queue should have picked unique row from CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

As of [JMeter 5.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-5.1) none of the [test elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) and [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) suitable for parameterization provides the behavior you're looking for.

You can use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) to script the CSV file reading in the way you want, for example you cat configure 1st virtual user to read 1st row, 2nd user - 2nd row, etc.

The relevant Groovy code would be something like:

- `${__groovy(new File('test.csv').readLines().get(ctx.getThreadNum()).split('\,')[0],)}` - gets the value from 1st column
- `${__groovy(new File('test.csv').readLines().get(ctx.getThreadNum()).split('\,')[1],)}` - gets the value from 2nd column

  Demo:

  [image]